# Asking a question about a particular error in code

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Well, I'm asking this because I have a particular nasty problem with some project I'm working on, but I'm unable to see what's going wrong. I have only been working for 2 years, so I'm quite tempeted to ask for help from more experienced developers, but I'm not sure if asking here would be correct.

What makes doubt about asking is just how especific is the question (a problem with sending/reciving encrypted information via sockets in .net).

So, what do you think? Is possible to ask such question in SO, posting code details? Or should I post more general questions about encryption and sockets till I'm able to complete the puzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask a specific question

Answer (score 2):

What I would advice would be to try to simplify your question in order to make it the more clearer you can. Sometimes when I ask question in a simple way, it make me find the answer by myself.

If your question is too complicated try to decompose the question in several small one!
Don't fear about asking, if no one can answer it at least you will have comment witch will help to reformulate it!

Answer (score 1):

As the FAQ says:

> Programming questions, of course! As long as your question is:
>
> - detailed and specific
> - written clearly and simply
> - of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere
>
> ... it is welcome here. No question is too trivial or too "newbie".

So, simply post whatever information is needed to solve your problem, as specifically as you like. Amongst the millions of programmers out there, somebody else will have had or someday will have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your best to identify the possible location of the problem. Then you'll have a question specific enough to ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can post detailed problems, as long as you make sure that the question is clear:

- Explain the exact nature of your problem (what do you see, what do you expect, what is the error, etc)
- Include relevant source code
- Omit irrelevant source code. Don't post 1000 lines of code when only one method of 50 lines actually causes the problem.

If you follow the above guidelines (they're only guidelines, nothing official or anything) then I don't see why a detailed questions with a specific problem is inappropiate. Hell, it might even be more appropiate than the question you're asking now! :-P

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same sort of situation, and managed to get great results by simplifying the problem (cleaning up sensitive information about the table in SQL, and removing columns irrelevant to the central problem), and then asking it.  As long as you're able to come up with a straight forward, answerable question, it's a wonderful way to get the problem solved.